# Why is current Oracle ODAC connectability not visible in VS 2013?

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2013, odac

I'm trying to setup my first Oracle database connection in Visual Studio 2013 and the only option available for the Data Source is a selection "Oracle Database". But that selection says it's deprecated (and it doesn't even allow me to choose the schema as I could do in VS2012, regardless, so it's unusable).

I already have an ODAC installed that works great for VS 2012 (11.2.0.3). Is there any way to get VS 2013 to recognize that I already have that installed (tried putting in a reference to the Oracle Data Client and that didn't work). Choosing "Other" doesn't provide me any other choices.

Am I forced to install ODAC 12c just so that VS 2013 sees it? Why wouldn't it see ODAC 11? I'd rather not do the 12c install due to other projects that rely on the older one (and, yes, we could go down a VM path, but that's not an immediate option).

Comment: You could just avoiding using any sort of separate OracleClient and used the [managed client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/odp.net.managed/). Makes life easy.

Comment: The reason I'm trying to use the ODAC is for Entity Framework. Since I did this post, I discovered that the drivers weren't ready for EF at the time but recently new drivers have been released. Those drivers are a bit quirky though. I also discovered that the designer will no longer be supported in EF, plus it appears the drivers don't allow for the database first model any more.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rerun the ODAC installer, you will be asked to reinstall .NET +.ASP components (I just excluded the examples package.)

My situation was a bit different: I Installed at first VS 2013 with ODAC and then VS 2012. The result was that VS 2012 didn't see the ODAC part: like you said the Data source with the "Oracle Database" choice. Rerunning the installer fixed this issue.
I think it's the same situation as mine. ODAC shouldn't be dependent on Visual Studio version but on the .NET framework  in use.