# How can I use Oracle Data Access Components 11.2.0 with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2013, odac

I am having a problem similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635226/why-is-current-oracle-odac-connectability-not-visible-in-vs-2013/28588335#28588335). However, the only answer suggested there doesn't work for me.

Specifically I am trying to upgrade from VS2010 to VS2013. I have an oracle database project (.oradbproj file type) as part of our main solution and it isn't recognized in 2013. I have ODAC 11.2.0 installed on the computer and I also tried to fix the problem by re-installing it after I installed VS2013. So far, nothign has worked.

Any Ideas?

**Edit, Additional information:** I have noticed that I am also missing the "Oracle Database Project" project template. I believe this was added to VS2010 by the ODAC, but it is not appearing in VS2013.

Comment: Please have a look at this question: [Oracle.DataAccess not available for selection in Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537783/oracle-dataaccess-not-available-for-selection-in-visual-studio-2013/28543212?noredirect=1#comment45429139_28543212)

Comment: I viewed the question that you linked to. It seems to be dealing with making a reference to the oracle data client. I can access it from the GAC with no apparent difficulty.

That isn't quite what I am doing. I am using an oracle project type (an .oradbproj file) to manage code related to the database itself. Somehow VS2013 needs to know to use ODAC to interpret the project file.

Comment: Check content of .oradbproj file with a text editor. Perhaps you have to re-write some folder names/locations in there.

Comment: Everything appears to be in order in the file except for three Oracle specific node types in the XML.

Comment: Additional information added above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found is to install Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio v. 12c.

--Jacob

Comment: I found where it is defined. Check your Registry for `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\AssemblyFoldersEx\ODP.NET` resp. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\ODP.NET`, there Visual Studio looks for references. Obviously this entry was added by the installation.